# Bootstrap проблема разметки

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Не получается сделать разметку сайта с помощью Bootstrap в виде:
контейнер
хедер на всю ширину в контейнере
3 - 6 - 3
футер на всю ширину в контейнере
/контейнер
В итоге сейчас разметка занимает слишком много места, и даже на ноутбуке она не влазит в экран, и содержимое прокручивается горизонтально скроллом. И вторая строка в итоге не 3-6-3, а как-то вовсе непонятно располагается.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">    
        <header class="col-md-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
                                data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NiceLogo</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
                                Login</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        </div>    

        <div class="row">
        <section class="col-md-3">sss</section>
        <section class="col-md-6">
            <div class="container">
               <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
               <!-- Indicators -->
                   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="car2.jpg" alt="paris Image 1" width="1160" height="245">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Modal Example</h1>
                            <h3>Situated on the Seine River. </h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="car2.jpg" alt="paris Image 2" width="1160" height="245">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Paris</h1>
                            <h3>Situated on the Seine River. </h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="car3.jpg" alt="paris Image 3" width="1160" height="245">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Paris</h1>
                            <h3>Paris was founded in the 3rd century BC </h3>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="car4.jpg" alt="paris Image 4" width="1160" height="245">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Paris</h1>
                            <h3>Paris is the home of the most visited art museum.</h3>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" 
                           data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" 
                                  aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" 
                           data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" 
                                  aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="col-md-3">sss</section>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
        <footer class="col-md-12"></footer>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: 1) зачем столько `container`? 
2) напишите ссылку на ваш сайт.

Comment: Сайт я только вот начал писать, на хостинг никуда не заливал.
Насчет такого количества контейнеров - то тут уже просто запутался, и пытался сделать желаемое любыми методами...
Собственно, два контейнера: для меню и карусели были в примере. И еще пару я прописал как в шаблонах, которые находил.

Comment: Убрал все контейнеры, по ширине все стало нормально, но почему-то во второй строке, где разметка 3-6-3, второй блок нормально отображается(6), а первый и третий(3) улетают за меню.

Comment: Хм, по прежнему второй блок нормально отображается, а первый и третий улетают за меню.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30684/discussion-between-alex-and-vyacheslav-martynenko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NiceLogo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                Sign Up</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
                                Login</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">test</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
          </ol>

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item">
              <img src="car2.jpg" alt="paris Image 1" width="1160" height="245">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Modal Example</h1>
                <h3>Situated on the Seine River. </h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="car2.jpg" alt="paris Image 2" width="1160" height="245">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Paris</h1>
                <h3>Situated on the Seine River. </h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="car3.jpg" alt="paris Image 3" width="1160" height="245">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Paris</h1>
                <h3>Paris was founded in the 3rd century BC </h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="car4.jpg" alt="paris Image 4" width="1160" height="245">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Paris</h1>
                <h3>Paris is the home of the most visited art museum.</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">test</div>
    </div>


    <div>
      <footer>test</footer>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```